# Pivot rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, pivot

I need to create one master table to present in reporting services, but i have an issue on how to combine the data. 
**To be more specific, i have one table named "Reservaciones" which store information from residences that have been reserved in certain dates.**

Now for example, I´m grouping the information by this fields:

1. R.ClaTrab AS WorkerId
2. R.ClaUbicacion AS UbicationID
3. R.ClaEstancia AS ResidenceID
4. R.FechaIni AS InitialDay
5. R.FechaFin AS LastDay

And the result is [First result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaX5o.png)

As you see in the picture we have two rows duplicated, the number four and number five to be exact.

So far this is my code

```
SELECT  
R.ClaTrab AS WorkerId,
MAX(E.NomEstancia) AS ResidenceName, 
R.ClaUbicacion AS UbicationID, 
R.ClaEstancia AS ResidenceID, 
DATEDIFF(DAY, R.FechaIni, R.FechaFin) AS NumberDays, 
R.FechaIni AS InitialDay,
R.FechaFin AS LastDay
FROM Reservaciones AS R
INNER JOIN Estancias AS E ON E.ClaEstancia = R.ClaEstancia
WHERE E.ClaUbicacionEst = 3
GROUP BY  R.ClaTrab,R.ClaUbicacion, R.ClaEstancia, R.FechaIni, R.FechaFin
ORDER BY R.FechaIni
```

I Want the result to be like this [desire result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDVmy.png),  but i dont know how to do it, i have tried PIVOT but i cant get the result i want it.

If u need more information please, ask me. 
thank you very much.

**SOLUTION:**
What i did is use the *ROW NUMBER()* and *OVER PARTITION BY* to create a group of workers in the same residence, then *PIVOT* the result in new columns.

***SNIPPET***

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT  
MAX(E.NomEstancia) AS ResidenceName,
R.FechaIni AS InitialDay,
R.FechaFin AS LastDay,
DATEDIFF(DAY, R.FechaIni, R.FechaFin) AS NumberDays, 
T.NomTrab AS Worker,
R.ClaUbicacion AS UbicationID, 
R.ClaEstancia AS ResidenceID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FechaIni,FechaFin, R.ClaUbicacion, R.ClaEstancia ORDER BY T.NomTrab) AS GUEST
FROM Reservaciones AS R
INNER JOIN Estancias AS E ON E.ClaEstancia = R.ClaEstancia
INNER JOIN Trabajadores AS T ON T.ClaTrab = R.ClaTrab
WHERE E.ClaUbicacionEst = 3
GROUP BY T.NomTrab, R.ClaUbicacion, R.ClaEstancia, R.FechaIni,R.FechaFin) AS ONE 
PIVOT( MAX(Worker) FOR GUEST IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS pvt
```

*In the new query I added a new join to obtain the name of the workers*

Comment: welcome to SO! Please use the following as a guide on how to post a good question on SO: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Take a look at this post on dynamic pivots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query/10404455#10404455

Comment: Will there only ever be two workers assigned, if not, is there any maximum that can be hardcoded?

Comment: Thanks Xedni,      Error_2646, in this particular case the max quantity of workers are two.

Comment: Since the max workers are two, then the solution below should work, no?

Comment: this is a particular case, but in some cases the workers can be three

Comment: You explicitly stated there would only be two.

Answer (score 0):

Since there can only be 2 workers, you can use Min and Max.

```
with cte as(
SELECT  
    R.ClaTrab AS WorkerId,
    MAX(E.NomEstancia) AS ResidenceName, 
    R.ClaUbicacion AS UbicationID, 
    R.ClaEstancia AS ResidenceID, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, R.FechaIni, R.FechaFin) AS NumberDays, 
    R.FechaIni AS InitialDay,
    R.FechaFin AS LastDay
FROM 
    Reservaciones AS R
INNER JOIN 
    Estancias AS E 
    ON E.ClaEstancia = R.ClaEstancia
WHERE 
    E.ClaUbicacionEst = 3
GROUP BY  
    R.ClaTrab,
    R.ClaUbicacion, 
    R.ClaEstancia, 
    R.FechaIni, 
    R.FechaFin),

cte2 as(
select
    ResidenceName
    ,UbicationID
    ,ResidenceID
    ,NumberDays
    ,InitalDay
    ,LastDay
    ,Worker1 = max(WorkerId)
    ,Worker2 = min(WorkerId)
from
    cte
group by
    ResidenceName
    ,UbicationID
    ,ResidenceID
    ,NumberDays
    ,InitalDay
    ,LastDay)

select
    ResidenceName
    ,UbicationID
    ,ResidenceID
    ,NumberDays
    ,InitalDay
    ,LastDay
    ,Worker1
    ,Worker2 = case when Worker1 = Worker2 then NULL else Worker2 end
from
    cte2
```

**[ONLINE DEMO WITH PARTIAL TEST DATA](http://rextester.com/EIYMW82378)**

Comment: I couldnt make it work, got errors on the cte2. Needed to create a group by clause

Comment: Sorry scsimon,  I was very confused wiht my code BUT I FOUND THE SOLUTION

Comment: Ok, why are you yelling at me?

Comment: Sorry i was excited,  wasn't yelling at you. I have days with this issue